# how to store the dataframe into csv files based on group pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe like below

```
id    B    C
1     2    3
1     3    4
2     4    2
3    12    32
```

finally I want to store the csv file
1.csv, 2.csv, 3.csv which contains all the rows specific to id column
Can I do this efficiently.I know we can do using for loop which is time consuming

Comment: I think multiprocessing is one of the options if you wanna do more faster than using for loop.

Answer (score 0):

From the Pandas DOC, the method from the **DataFrame** you have to write the content in CSV file is **to_csv**. Looks like there is no specific parameter to optimize it for you.

As you can see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#writing-to-csv-format).

You can solve this problem in an O(n) operation, considering ordered IDs. You already have the entire **DataFrame** in memory. By saving pieces in single files you also can free some space in memory by splitting the entire DataFrame each loop step.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Lazyer, you can use `multiprocessing`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def to_csv(name, df):
    df.to_csv(f'export/{name}.csv', index=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':  # Do not remove this line! Mandatory
    # Setup a minimal reproducible example
    N = 10_000_000
    rng = np.random.default_rng(2022)
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10000, (N, 3)),
                      columns=['id', 'B', 'C'])

    # Multi processing
    start = time.time()
    with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
        pool.starmap(to_csv, df.groupby('id'))
    end = time.time()
    print(f"[MP] Elapsed time: {end - start:.2f} seconds")

    # Single processing
    start = time.time()
    for name, subdf in df.groupby('id'):
        subdf.to_csv(f'export/{name}.csv', index=False)
    end = time.time()
    print(f"[SP] Elapsed time: {end - start:.2f} seconds")
```

Test for 10,000,000 records:

```
[...]$ python mp.py
[MP] Elapsed time: 2.99 seconds
[SP] Elapsed time: 12.97 seconds
```

Comment: Does it solve your problem?